# Remontar data com javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

No meu banco tenho um campo DateTime. No meu form eu três combos para: Dia, Mês e Ano. Tenho uma função JavaScript, que serializa as informações, enviando-as para meu controller gravar. Acontece que a data está vindo nula. Tentei fazer assim, mas não dá certo.

```
DataNascimento:
    ($("input[name='txtAno']").val() + "-" +
    $("input[name='txtMes']").val() + "-" +
    $("input[name='txtDia']").val()),
```

Como eu remonto a data no javascript?

Comment: São combos ou textbox?

Answer (score 2):

Bem, sua pergunta é **"Como eu remonto a data no javascript?"** E eu te respondo, é simples, para montar uma Data você tem o Objeto Date do Javascript:

```
var a = $("input[name='txtAno']").val(); //ano
var m = $("input[name='txtMes']").val(); //mes
var d = $("input[name='txtDia']").val(); //dia
var data = new Date(a,(m-1),d); //o m-1 é porque o mês do javascript é zero-indexed.
```

Logo você terá uma Data remontada em javascript, e você pode usar para a sua função.

Answer (score 0):

Estou vendo que você já possui os inputs da data desmembrados, você poderia criar uma action, que ao invés de receber uma data, receba também as partes desmembradas:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(int txtAno, int txtMes, int txtDia)
{
    var data = new DateTime(txtAno, txtMes, txtDia);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma biblioteva de js na internet outro dia que me ajudou bastante com problemas relacionados a data em Javascript. Segue o link para download da biblioteca:

[DATE JS](http://www.datejs.com/)